# Display page load time on node.js with angular ui grid from start to finishing data load and display

Tags: angularjs, json, angular-ui-grid, page-load-time

I have a `node.js` application return a `html` file using `res.sendfile`, and the html file displays a `angular ui grid` retrieving `json` data from an `url`.

The page displays first with an empty grid, then the grid is filled with the json rows as they come.

I want to display on the returned page the `load time` from initial request to final display of complete downloaded data ?

I have used `var loadTime = window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd-window.performance.timing.navigationStart;` but it displays only up to the display of the page with an empty grid, it does not wait until the data retrieving is completed.

**html**

```
<html ng-app="app">
    <head>
        <script src="angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.css" />
        <script src="angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.js"></script>
        <script src="ng.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="myctrl">
            <div ui-grid="mygrid" class="grid"></div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            var loadTime = window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd-window.performance.timing.navigationStart;
            console.log('Page load time is '+ loadTime);
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**ng.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.grid']);
app.controller('myctrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/api/mydata').success(function(data) {
        $scope.mygrid.data = data;
    }
}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: you haven't shown any code here, making it very difficult to accurately tell you how to fix the issue.  However, I might *suggest* that if you are using `$http` to request your data, the end of the data request is the `.then` method of the `$http` call.

Comment: I have added some code

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I managed to have it working by using `var ngloadTime = new Date() - window.performance.timing.navigationStart;` inside the success function

Comment: you should also consider using `.then` instead of the deprecated `.success`.  `.then` provides the `response` object instead of just the `data`, meaning you have direct access to additional information, such as HTTP status codes.